# Java nested types scenarios

Tags: java

I'm trying to think of a situation where I might need to declare a non static inner type(class) inside another class (other than the situation discussed below), lets consider the following code

```
public class OuterClass {

    public int OuterMember;

    public static class StaticInner{
        public int x;
    }

    public class NonStaticInner{
        public int x;
        public int y = OuterMember; // none static nested type can access parent members
    }

    public NonStaticInner getNonStaticInner(){
        return new NonStaticInner();
    }
}

public class TestClass {
    public OuterClass.StaticInner staticObject = new OuterClass.StaticInner();
    public OuterClass outer = new OuterClass();
    public OuterClass.NonStaticInner nonStaticObject = outer.getNonStaticInner();

    public TestClass()
    {
        nonStaticObject.y = 5;
        nonStaticObject.x = 7;
        staticObject.x = 2;
    }
}
```

now my question is: if I didn't need a closure inside nonStaticObject or in other words if I didn't need to access "OuterMember" from inside NonStaticInner, is there any value of declaring NonStaticInner as non static? after all I can create as many instances as I want of either NonStaticInner or StaticInner , except that for StaticInner I don't need an instance of "OuterClass"

Comment: You should generally prefer static unless the inner class is tied to a specific instance of the outer class.

Comment: There is no such thing in Java as a "static inner class" because by definition an inner class in Java is a non-static nested class.

Comment: @LewBloch I meant to say (or actually did) static inner type

Comment: It's worthwhile to point out that your `NonStaticInner` doesn't need to be an inner class either. The access it makes to `OuterMember` could be replaced with a constructor.

Comment: The code example also shows 'public static class StaticInner'. And Java does not have any such thing as "static inner type", by definition.

Comment: @LewBloch I'm really not sure what confusion is about. "StaticInner" is a static nested type that I declared. its isn't a type that comes with java! I could had named it anything!

Comment: The confusing thing is that you refer to "static inner type" and name one "StaticInner", when there is no such thing as a static inner type in Java. Variable and type names convey a meaning to maintainers, and the meaning conveyed by 'StaticInner' is of a "static inner" type, which can't exist in Java, so it is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason to create an inner (i.e., non-static nested) class in Java is to have it tied to the containing instance, such as to access the outer instance's members. For example, event handlers in AWT/Swing are commonly declared as inner class instances, giving them access to the instance members of, say, the JPanel whose events they handle. Prior to lambdas, inner classes were used frequently as functor types, and today lambdas often translate to inner classes.

It's pretty clear that when a class needs access to its containing type's members that it should be an inner class. It's less clear when you declare a static nested class that it should be a nested class. After all, it works just like a top-level class (of either 'public' or default access). So why not make it a top-level class? The answer is that you deem the nested type to be too tightly bound to the functionality of the containing type to merit promotion to the top level. Typically this means that the containing type needs the nested type, but no one else does or ever will.

Comment: Thanks, just to make sure I understand what you said, are you saying that declaring a static nested type is somewhat counter intuitive, since it still can be treated as (or actually is ) an outer type. coz even though "no one else does or ever will need the nested type" it can still be accessed and treated as an outer type

Comment: `Map.Entry` is perhaps the most canonical example of a static nested type. It's nested purely as a means of association.

Comment: I'm not saying that static nested types are counterintuitive. I'm saying that it's less clear when you should use one than it is with inner classes. Also, it is not true that a static nested type "actually is .. an outer type". It actually is not. Nor can you treat it as one or access it as one.